# Get an error when try to consume wcf service with nettcpbinding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, nettcpbinding

I created wcf service with nettcpbinding(security mode="None"). Hosted it on IIS..
it run in browser:

```
net.tcp://localhost/NetTcptest/Service1.svc/mex
```

When i consume this service using service reference it work.
but when i try consume using channel factory than it gives error:

> This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions
>   between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between
>   the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the
>   same contract and the same binding (including security requirements,
>   e.g. Message, Transport, None).

I am not understanding what is wrong in my code.

my service web config is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--All Bindings Information-->
    <bindings>
       <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="None" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--All Service Information-->
    <services>
      <service name="NetTcpTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="netTcpServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="NetTcpTest"
                  contract="NetTcpTest.IService1"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"/>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses >
            <!--<add baseAddress ="http://localhost:8080"/>-->
            <add baseAddress ="net.tcp://localhost/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="netTcpServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also my test application code is:

```
private void CallService_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                string _uri = "net.tcp://localhost/NetTcptest/Service1.svc/mex";
                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
                binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
                binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None;
                binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
                EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(_uri);
                ChannelFactory<IService1> channel = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);
                IService1 clientProxy = channel.CreateChannel();
                label1.Text = clientProxy.GetData(100);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is you're constructing your client channel configuration in code. Try using config and copy the config file from the service, changing it to define a client channel. Or use the generate service reference config and change use it from your channelfactory.

Comment: Check Client's App.Config file.

Comment: thanx for reply, But i want to construct it in code, not in app config file....